# Convert float value greater than 0.5 to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I need to allow float values and convert any floating value greater than `0.5` to `1`. For example:

```
0.4 = 0.4
0.5 = 0.5
0.6 = 1
```

I have tried using Math references like below, but not suiting my requirement.

```
var intvalue = Math.floor( floatvalue );
var intvalue = Math.ceil( floatvalue ); 
var intvalue = Math.round( floatvalue );
```

Also `var a = parseFloat("10.5")` is not giving what I expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "no use" and "not giving expected result"? Both `Math.ceil` and `parseFloat` worked as *I* expected.

Comment: only if x > 5, make it 1. It could be 0.7, 0.8 or 1.8.

Comment: So if `1.8` expected result is `1` or `2`??? Why don't you ask a clear question???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xb5yLsbp/1/):

```
$("input.number").blur(function() {
    if( this.value % 1 > 0.5 ) {
        this.value = Math.round(this.value);
    }
});
```

Enter some number greater than `20.5` like `20.51` and click outside the input to see it rounding to `21`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
if(intvalue > 0.5){
    intvalue = 1;
}
```

if intvalue is greater than 0.5, then intvalue is 1.

Comment: How can I use it in <input type> ?

Answer (score -1):

According to the `@Koen Hoeijmakers` answer, you can try with:

```
var input = 10.5;

if ( input % 1 != 0.5 ) {
  input = Math.round(input);
}
```

Comment: how can i use this value when user types in <input type="text"/>

Comment: I guess you mean `input % 1 > 0.5` this is how i understand this so unclear question

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Ok, so you want for any value > 0.5, the input to act as interger input, not more accepting float numbers, is it???